# How to set font-family in HTML select dropdown list in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, html-select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change css font-family for separate options in select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672960/change-css-font-family-for-separate-options-in-select-tag)
>   [Styling options in bold in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655625/styling-options-in-bold-in-internet-explorer)

I am not able to set font-family of a dropdown list of HTML select in IE8,9. **Is it a bug/property or am I doing something wrong?** Font-size setting works. The example is too extreme my real problem is that I have different font on the page and in the list. 
 I don't care about IE7-.

**Example( http://jsfiddle.net/SDcLX/11/):**

I have following HTML:

```
aaaaa
<div class="container">
skjhlks <select>
    <option class="courier">courier</option>
    <option>aa</option>
    <option style="font-family:impact;" selected="selected"  >bb</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.container
  {
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:Lucida Handwriting;
   }
select
{
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
}

option.courier
 {
    font-family:courier;
 }
```

The result in FF is:

[image]

and in IE:

[image]

Comment: It is at least similar but what is not stated is that it is a problem of IE. My aim is to have the same font as in other part of my page or to have a statement that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The question is also a duplicate of [styling options in bold in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655625/styling-options-in-bold-in-internet-explorer)

Apparently IE uses the operationg system to render the controls.

Perhaps you can use a js widget instead like [this one](http://lindekleiv.bitbucket.org/fontselector/#)
It takes a basic select but transorms it with jquery.